# Copy program from CD to USB but can't launch program after installation in window-10

Tags: windows-10, usb, installation, compact-disc

I transferred the files from the CD to the USB, then installed the computer, which did not have a DVD/CD drive. However, after the installation, after I click the.exe file, it looks for a CD/DVD drive. It has not shown any errors during the installation process of the USB. Could you please advise?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbwJf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMLZe.png)

It works fine on the computer that has the physical optical drive (using recommended installation, installed directly from the optical drive). But working with computer which no optical drive, after I converted to .ISO, mounted on window-10 --> installation --> it  is still looking for CD/DVD as image shown below. How do I solve this?

[image]

If I use WinCDEmu.exe, it still shows the wrong disc insertion. Please advise.

Comment: lots of old software required you to have a legitimate CD/DVD of the software in the drive in order to run the software. this was done to prevent people from pirating the software. there probably isn't a good way to proceed without access to a CD/DVD drive at least once, so pick up a usb drive. they're pretty cheap. the first thing to try is creating an .iso image of the disk, putting it on the USB, and copying it to the harddisk. if you mount the .iso file as a virtual drive (built-in functionality on win10/11), you can try the software again.

Comment: Did you do the "full" installation?  You can find the information on this [here](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/dictionaries/support/ldoce-updated-support.html#w6).  As @FrankThomas points out, this software is very old.. but this appears to be intentional when installing anything but "full" from the disk image.

Comment: If the program uses no "advanced" copy protection mechanisms, you could simply create a .iso and mount it in a virtual drive. You could use daemon tools for that

Answer (score 0):

1- Copy Program to folder in Your PC and do it in .ISO
2- install Your Program
3- Download WinCDEmu.exe From ==> https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/portable/
4- Open WinCDEmu.exe and Mount image there

Done :)

[image]

Comment: i do this to play Old Pc game ;D