# How do I redirect the virtual disk drive to open the program which requiring physical optical drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, compact-disc, optical-drive, virtual-drive

Refer to this Q: [Copy program from CD to USB but can't launch program after installation in window-10](https://superuser.com/questions/1707829/copy-program-from-cd-to-usb-but-cant-launch-program-after-installation-in-windo)

I observed that I needed to put the CD into the physical optical drive after installation. However, my current computer does not have an optical drive, and the program is looking for a disc after I first launch the rpogram. I did create the virtual optical drive through either window-10 or PortableWinCDEmu but the program can not recognize. Is there any ways to solve the issue?
[image][image]

Comment: What about a USB Optical Drive and then pass through to the VM. I do it this way here.

Comment: @John I don't a USB optical drive. I have .ISO file in the USB.

Comment: Simply put, it may not be possible at all even with drive emulation. Many commercial software of that vintage had many copy protection systems to avoid (1) a simple disk copy or (2) exactly what you're doing. Same suggestion as before: Get a USB optical drive.

Comment: @John This is not about a VM.

Comment: I mis-read but a USB drive is still the best way to go.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the information, I will try "Share CD and DVD drives over Windows network" [link](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/use-cd-dvd-computer-no-disk-drive), I have another desktop that contains an optical drive.

Comment: If the problem is copy protection that won't work either.